# How to access element in array object [API]

Tags: reactjs, api

```
result: [,…]

0: {id: "58cdb1a0", type: "b", nextDate: null, status: "active",…}
Date: "2019-11-27T11:10:23.000Z"
id: "58cdb1b86"
nextDate: null
status: "active"
type: "b"

1: {id: "e7b07030-799d-43", type: "l", nextDate: "2019-12-11T00:00:00.000Z",…}
Date: null
id: "e7b07030"
nextDate: "2019-12-11T00:00:00.000Z"
status: "active"
type: "l"
```

Then I want to access type ===b element object

```
const details = this.state.Method.filter((element: any) => element.type === 'b');
```

Then I want to get those object elements

```
console.log('details.nextDate');
```

But console getting undefined. Can you please help me to resolve it?

Comment: Need to see more code. Can't see anything wrong with your details constant or the filter.
So I suspect it may have something to do with the way you are setting state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter will return an array. So you can read the output as

```
console.log(details[0].nextDate);
```

OR

You can use `find`, which will return an object.

```
const details = this.state.Method.find((element: any) => element.type === 'b');
```

Now you can use

```
console.log(details.nextDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(details[0].nextDate);
```

The filter() method **creates a new array**.